# Any ideas why QHash and QMap return const T instead of const T&?

Tags: c++, qt, hash, reference, performance

Unlike std::map and std::hash_map, corresponding versions in Qt do not bother to return a reference. Isn't it quite inefficient, if I build a hash for quite bulky class?

**EDIT**

especially since there is a separate method value(), which could then return it by value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does QMap::operator\[\](const Key & key) return by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503700/why-does-qmapoperatorconst-key-key-return-by-value)

Comment: @ThomasKlier sure, just asked 5 years earlier

Answer (score 29, accepted):

const subscript operators of `STL` containers can return a reference-to-const because they flat out deny calls to it with indexes that do not exist in the container. Behaviour in this case is undefined. Consequently, as a wise design choice, `std::map` doesn't even provide a const subscript operator overload.

QMap tries to be a bit more accommodating, provides a const subscript operator overload as syntactic sugar, runs into the problem with non-existing keys, again tries to be more accomodating, and returns a default-constructed value instead.

If you wanted to keep STL's return-by-const-reference convention, you'd need to allocate a static value and return a reference to *that*. That, however, would be quite at odds with the reentrancy guarantees that `QMap` provides, so the only option is to return by value. The `const` there is just sugar coating to prevent some stupid mistakes like `constmap["foo"]++` from compiling.

That said, returning by reference is not always the most efficient way. If you return a fundamental type, or, with more aggressive optimisation, when `sizeof(T)<=sizeof(void*)`, return-by-value often makes the compiler return the result in a register directly instead of indirectly (address to result in register) or—heaven forbid—on the stack.

The other reason (besides premature pessimisation) to prefer pass-by-const-reference, slicing, doesn't apply here, since both `std::map` and `QMap` are value-based, and therefore homogeneous. For a heterogeneous container, you'd need to hold pointers, and pointers are fundamental types (except smart ones, of course).

That all said, I almost never use the const subscript operator in Qt. Yes, it has nicer syntax than `find()`+`*it`, but invariably, you'll end up with `count()`/`contains()` calls right in front of the const subscript operator, which means you're doing the binary search *twice*. And *then* you won't notice the miniscule differences in return value performance anyway :)

For `value() const`, though, I agree that it should return reference-to-const, defaulting to the reference-to-default-value being passed in as second argument, but I guess the Qt developers felt that was too much magic.

Comment: "std::map's const subscript operator..."  But `std::map` doesn't have a `const` subscript operator?

Comment: "they flat out deny calls to it with indexes that do not exist in the container" but you can do this on std::map, that's one way to insert new values. But even if you meant in the general case, how does it follow on that they don't provide a const subscript operator?

Comment: One of the design guidelines for the STL was to not provide operations that are not possible in an efficient way. That's why `std::map` has no const subscript operator and `std::list` doesn't have a subscript operator at all.

Comment: good point about making binary search _twice_. But what if I know that the elements are there? I just need to know what they map to...

Comment: For defensive programming alone, you will add `assert( map.count( X )' anyway, and I have seen too  much software shipped with asserts enabled to dismiss any claim that asserts are not performance-critical as wishful thinking.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz, may i ask you to have a look at this question on another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116963/bangla-language-not-displayed-in-the-unicoded-csv-file ?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for QMap and QHash specifically say to avoid `operator[]` for lookup due to the reason Martin B stated.

If you want a const reference, use `const_iterator find ( const Key & key ) const` where you can then use any of:

```
const Key & key () const
const T & value () const
const T & operator* () const
const T * operator-> () const
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, some of the methods *do* return a reference... for example, the non-const version of `operator[]` returns a `T &`.

However, the const version of `operator[]` returns a `const T`. Why? As "unwind" has already noted, the reason has to do with what happens when the key does not exist in the map. In the non-const `operator[]`, we can add the key to the map, then return a reference to the newly added entry. However, the const `operator[]` can't do this because it can't modify the map. So what should it return a reference to? The solution is to make the const `operator[]` return `const T`, and then return a default-constructed `T` in the case where the key is not present in the map.

Comment: I would prefer having operator[] behaviour the same as that of std:: and value() method to return it by value...

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't `const T QHash::value(const Key &key, const T &defaultValue) const` return a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Weird, yes.

Perhaps this is because of the desired semantics, where doing e.g. `value()` on an unspecified key, returns a default-constructed value of the proper type. That's not possible using references, at least not as cleanly.

Also, things like [name return value optimization](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx) can lessen the performance impact of this design.