# Why does QMap::operator[](const Key & key) return by value?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I noticed that the `QMap::operator[](const Key & key)` has these two [overloads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d):

```
    T & QMap::operator[](const Key & key)
const T QMap::operator[](const Key & key) const
```

**Is there a reason for returning by value?**

And since we have move semantics:

**when returning by value, should we ever return by const value?**

The reason why I am asking is this:

Imagine we have:

```
class ExpensiveToCopy;
{
public:
    int someProperty() const;
    ...
}

void f(const QMap<int, ExpensiveToCopy>& map)
{
    int lala = map[4].someProperty(); // We need to copy the entire object
                                      // just to look at someProperty();
}
```

Comment: Only *one* overload return by value, the other returns a reference.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, that is the thing that I do not understand. Shouldn't they both return a reference like for example std::vector::operator[] ?

Comment: @nurettin it *does* inhibit move semantics.

Comment: Returning a const value *does* prevent move. Move constructors are faster *because* they are allowed to change the originating value, so const will prevent that.

Comment: You would need `const QMap<int, ExpensiveToCopy> map;` in your example to trigger the `const` overload.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the the `const` case we can not add an element to the `const` map if it does not already exist, so a local object will be returned.

Otherwise, in the non-`const` case, an element will be created with the specified key (if there isn't one already) before returning a reference to it.

Comment: This is exactly it. I was just about to write the same answer. Note `std::map` has no `const operator[]`, and it is probably a good thing. Less confusing.

Comment: Specifically: the `const` case must be able to return a "default" constructed element without inserting anything into the map in case an element with the given key isn't found in the map. So it cannot return a reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza It could return a reference to a static local variable, so it is possible to return a const reference. Whether one wants to, is a different matter...

Comment: @Sjoerd True. Also, this doesn't explain why a `const` value is returned. I think it is a bad idea to have the `const` overload, unless you are willing to introduce bound checks.

Comment: @juanchopanza they probably made the value `const` so that something like `const_map['k'].someMutatingMemberFn()` doesn't happen, where the intent was to modify the object contained in the map, not the temporary, which makes sense in C++98 but is a bad idea in C++11 (as it prevents move). Preventing such abuse is still possible in C++11 via reference qualifiers. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834937/isnt-the-const-modifier-here-unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I think non reference `const` is to ensure client code can't modify `map` by any ways. you know if use `const_cast<ExpensiveToCopy>map[4]` or other ways, we still can modify `map[4]`, but this `map[4]` is not reference to 4th element of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

It's also not possible to store a Value type with const members, since returning by value requires Value::operator=().  It seems to me the const version of QMap::operator[] is ill-conceived.  The same effect could be produced by calling contains() and at().  This is an example of a convenience function that is, well, inconvenient.